# Vim macro to copy paste text

Tags: key-bindings, macro

I would like to copy paste everything after a comment into the `[]` place holder of the next line.

E.g.:

```
%This is a comment
Target box: [] with some more text
```

The desired output would be:

```
%This is a comment
Target box: [This is a comment] with some more text
```

I am trying to do a macro to achieve this (but am quite new to Vim) and I would appreciate your help.

So far I put my cursor anywhere on the commented line:

```
Esc > 0 > l > SHIFT RIGHT (to select the rest of the line) > y > j > f[ > p
```

But it doesn't work as I expect. I am using the Vim keybindings in Overleaf as I edit some LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do (assuming you run the macro from Normal mode):

```
0lyg_+f[p
```

Or:

```
^[0lyg_+f[p
```

If you plan to run the macro from insert mode.

Where `^[` stand for <kbd>Esc</kbd>

- `0` go to the start of the line
- `l` move one character right
- `yg_` yank (copy) till the end of the line not including the carriage return
- `+` move to the first non blank character of the next line
- `f[` search for the first `[`
- `p` paste

Remark: But on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) you have to replace `yg_` by `y$` since the `g_` key command is not supported and replaced by `y$` (like for [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/))

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. On my end the yg_ doesn't seem to work - it also copies the next line. Could it be an issue with overleaf?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I have no access to overleaf :-/ my answer was assuming Vim or Neovim. You could try `y$` or `v$y` instead.

Comment: thanks so much, yes ```y$``` works

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (I also tested on Overleaf in the meantime :-) ).

Comment: Golf! `+` is a keystroke shorter than `j0`

Comment: Nice :-) I'll adapt the solution accordingly.

Comment: Nitpicking! `+` equals `j^`, not `j0` (doesn't make a difference, though)

Comment: Thanks I have adapted the solution accordingly :-)

Comment: Even if there were whitespace at the start of the line, we'd want to skip it.

Comment: @Rich we both know you're right :-)

Comment: Just realized I accidentally caused an improvement of the answer with my nitpicking comment. Believe me, that was never my intention. Apparently, I can't even write something stupid.

Comment: @Friedrich high fives all round :D